# Reading and saving big data to db

Tags: c#, object-oriented, database

I have a method for reading data from file. The problem is how to handle files that are too big for a simple read and save to database? I was thinking about reading a chunk of it and saving it to database, but I don't know if having an asynchronous method with callback is a good idea.

Basically I think that a reader class shouldn't be aware of any database interface, so in order to notify of successfully reading a chunk of data it has to have a callback. I don't know if this is a good approach or not.

```
private const int Buffer = 100000;

    public Task ReadAsync(Action<Tuple<DataTable, int>> statusCallback) {
        DataTable data;
        return await Task.Run(() => {
            var totalRows = GetRowsCount(); // iterates file to calculate total number of rows
            var progress = 0;
            if(totalRows < Buffer) {
                /**Read whole file...*/
              progress = 100;
            }
            else {
              while(/**loop until end of file*/) {
                   for(var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < Buffer; rowIndex++) { 
                      var row = reader.Read();
                      /**Split, parse, etc...*/
                      data.Add(row);
                   }
                progress += Buffer/totalRows * 100; // Add read rows to total result %
                statusCallback(new Tuple(data, progress));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And then save it

```
public void Start() {
    _reader.ReadAsync(ReadingProgress);
}

private void ReadingProgress(DataTable data, int progress) {
     _loadingBar.Update(progress);
     using(var tran = _database.BeginTrans()) {
         foreach(var row in data.Rows) 
         {
             _database.Insert(row);
         }
         tran.Commit();
     }
}
```

For some reason it seems wrong to me, but I don't know why. Any ideas how I could improve this?

EDIT:
I would like to notify users of how much the program read of the file, so I need to iterate through the whole file once and read how many lines it has. This bothers me, because it means I have to iterate a file two times.

One approach I thought about was get the byte size of first line and then divide the size of the file by that size. It would give me estimated count of lines in a file, but I'm not really sure if the approximation error wouldn't be too big.

Comment: A producer consumer with a throttle an the producer if it gets too far ahead.

Comment: I miss the loop over all chunks of data in your code. In the current form, the code will only read the first chunk. When you add the missing loop, you have to make sure the calls to `_database.Insert` stay in the right order, even when multiple threads are involved. Or, you have to make sure the order of insert does not matter.

Comment: ... now things got even more confusing. Inserts by column? Still not showing where the code loops over the chunks? Voting to close as "unclear".

Comment: ... is this a try to fix the question? Inserting all rows of one chunk still does not show how multiple chunks are processed. If you do not understand my comments, ask instead of applying wild guesses.

Comment: @DocBrown I fixed what I could before going to work. I've just added the rest. I don't need exact line by line fix. I just want to know if my thinking is good in terms of keeping everything separate and clean.

Comment: Ok, after your edit it got clear your code does processes all chunks in correct order, not in different threads (which was not inherently clear before). But now it looks overcomplicated to make a distinction for `totalRows < Buffer`, or why you use a Buffer at all - why not read one record at a time and directly insert it? To avoid increasing the progress indicator in every loop, you do not need to introduce an extra buffer.

Comment: I added transaction to speed it up. Buffer dictates the size of transaction.

Comment: Why not report progress based on the number of bytes processed (over total bytes), instead of lines? The user probably does not care about the difference.

Comment: @FrankHileman thanks, that's true. I overcomplicated it, as I always do :)